# Changing the background color of an html checkbox

Tags: html, checkbox, background-color

Is it possible, and if so how, to change the background color on an HTML checkbox?  I'm specifically talking about the white box that is behind the little check symbol.

I've searched quite a bit on this but haven't found a conclusive answer yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only using scripts you can achieve a cross browser solution, [see an example here of a styled checkbox...](http://www.mosarte.com.br/produto).

It is using **[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)** to change the style

Comment: This example is exactly what I was looking for.  I have no problem using scripts to implement the solution.  Here's a follow-up question.  **Does jQuery do this natively, or should a specific plugin be used?**  (I tried searching for a plugin but couldn't find one; however, their search isn't that great.)

Comment: It is a jQuery UI widget. I don't really know how to use it, a co-worker showed me once. There is a tutorial here that is using it http://www.tuttoaster.com/enhancing-forms-using-jquery-ui/

Comment: Yeah, I see that you did indeed include a link for a plugin.  On first glance I thought that was just the jQuery link.  Thanks for the help, and also for your latest link!

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that is possible since the check box appearance is OS-specific anyway (my checkboxes have a *shaded* gray background, not a white one).

A solution could be to build your own checkbox using JavaScript and some graphics.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK only Opera supports the "background" CSS statement for formular elements.

For further information, check this out: http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/checkbox/

Comment: I've viewed this site before, but the information seems a bit dated.  The newest browser tested here is IE7 in Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff B showed [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986608/css-styling-checkboxes) to color a checkbox. He also provided a jsfiddle example.

The idea is to wrap a span and use a png image with some javascript and css.

Answer (score 0):

I am implementing the colour Check box I thought it will be easy to do the color check box but  when I started to implement it. it was so time taken Job to do the first time. below is the HTML and CSS for the COLOUR CHECK BOX any one can customized as well this HTML and CSS.

HTML :-

```
<div class="squaredThree left">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree" name="check" />
    <label for="squaredThree"></label>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
.squaredThree {
    width: 20px;    
    position: relative;
}

.squaredThree label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    top: 0;
    background:#f7f7f7;
    border:1px solid #6d7279;
}

.squaredThree label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    border: 3px solid #0b9dda;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredThree label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```