# Customize CSS for indeterminate state checkbox

Tags: css, checkbox

I have a feature that enables tristate check boxes.

Following is the snapshot of the check boxes that appear in Chrome:

[image]

The third checkbox in the snapshot above has `indeterminate` state. This state has browser specific CSS.

I need to change the CSS of third checkbox to look something like: [image]

I am fairly new to CSS. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css There are lots of tutorials/samples/generators and stuff.

Comment: what browsers do you have to cover?

Comment: @keaukraine thanks for the link. I'll try them.

Comment: @albert I would like to cover almost all browsers available.

Comment: Got you covered with my answer @varunvlalan, across all compatible browsers.

Answer (score 4):

### This is the `:indeterminate` selector..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:indeterminate

```
tag.class:indeterminate {}
```

In this case you can change the `background:` attribute to the image you like.

Something along the lines of:

```
tag.class:indeterminate {
    background: url("/image");
}
```

I recommend you look into this handling of `:checked` for styling your checkboxes:

- [Change checkbox check image to custom image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270987/change-checkbox-check-image-to-custom-image)

**EDIT:** Or as @FelixLahmer added, use: http://www.csscheckbox.com/css-checkbox-generator.php

Comment: I dont want to create another answer, but may add that you can generate it very easily using http://www.csscheckbox.com/css-checkbox-generator.php

Comment: Implemented using what @FelixLahmer suggested. Thanks.