# Make radio button required, when using a custom image radio button

Tags: javascript, css, radio-button

My issue is that I am using custom images for my radio buttons, so I have them set to display:none; but doing this means they are no longer being called out as required.

Is there a simple solution for this? The radio buttons MUST be images.

-Thanks

```
<label for="topsides">Top Sides</label>

<form action="" id="TopSideYearCubics_id">
<input class="radio" id="topsidescubicsides" type="radio" name="properties[Top Sides]" value="Cubic Sides" required="required">
<a id="topsidescubicsides_button" href="javascript:set_radio('topsidescubicsides');" class="radio-picture-150x150"  style="background: url(http://www.xxxx.com/_Store/_images2015/customring_buttons/button_CA01test_topsides_cubics.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 0;">&nbsp;</a>

<input class="radio" id="topsidesyearsides" type="radio" name="properties[Top Sides]" value="Year Sides">
<a id="topsidesyearsides_button" href="javascript:set_radio('topsidesyearsides');" class="radio-picture-150x150" style="background: url(http://www.xxxx.com/_Store/_images2015/customring_buttons/button_CA01test_topsides_years.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 0;">&nbsp;</a>

</form>
      <br />


<script>
  <!-- //## Sets the Image to the Radio Button ##//-->
function set_radio($inputid) {
$("input#" + $inputid).click();
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a.radio-picture-150x150").click(function(){
        var $id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("a.radio-picture-150x150").removeClass('selected-border');
        $("a#" + $id).addClass('selected-border');
    });
});
</script>
<style>

input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
display:none;
}

</style>
```

Comment: use pseudo-elements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991071/radio-button-with-custom-image

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p1wkkwfx/

Comment: display: none still means that the REQUIRED will not work.

[jsfiddle.net/r8h7v70c/](http://jsfiddle.net/r8h7v70c/)

Comment: `input[type=radio][required] { position: absolute; left: -10000px; }`?

Answer (score 0):

In my CSS, I just gave the `input[type="radio"]` a style of `opacity:0;` to get rid of the stock button, but still show the browser's "Please select one of these options" validation tool-tip when one of my custom radio images wasn't chosen.