# How to Change `collection_check_boxes` into X Boxes (aka ticks into crosses)?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

With this...

```
  <%= f.label "Level 1:" %>&nbsp;
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :missed, Habit::ONEMISSED, :downcase, :to_s %>
```

I get this (assuming the user clicked on the first checkbox):

```
[ √ ]"X"  [  ]"X"  [  ]"X"
```

What would I need instead so that when the user clicks on a checkbox it shows an X instead of a checkmark?

For example:

```
[ X ]  [  ]  [  ]
```

The latter case looks cleaner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change checkbox check image to custom image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270987/change-checkbox-check-image-to-custom-image)

Comment: None of those suggestions seems to be working for me.