# How to make a custom checkbox with image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I need to create a checkbox with an image in it, instead of regular checkmark. It should look like this, **[ticked]:** [image]

**[Unticked]:** [image]

**Here is the code of the element:**

```css
.modal-options label {
  color: #f62b3e;
  font-family: sharp-20-regular;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.modal-options input {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #f62b3e;
}

.modal-options input:checked {
  background-position: right center;
}

.checkmark {
  background-image: url(assets/images/checkbox-smile.svg);
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
      

  <label>
       <input type="checkbox" />
       <span class="checkmark"></span>
       <br />
       Just curious
</label>
```

**This is what I have currently:**
[image]

Comment: [Try this](https://codepen.io/jouanmarcel/pen/MXdreK) link , it's very helpful

Comment: @justDan Yes it did!
Particularly this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13953070/9136921

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `<div>` and put the checkbox inside that `<div>`.

Then first use the background property to set an image as `background` in this parent `div`, that fills the entire element. Then, make the checkbox big as the parent element, after that, change the opacity of the `checkbox` to 0.

If you did all of that right, once the user clicks the image, the checkbox will be also clicked.