# Onclick function inside blade check box

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am using blade template check box. I want to make it checked and readonly. So that i find other way to make it readonly by using onclick function. On onclick function using Jquery make the checkbox readonly. But how to assign function inside blade checkbox ?. Is there any way to make it both checked and readonly.

```
{{Form::checkbox('allRole[]', $allRole->name,true)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
{{Form::checkbox('allRole[]', $allRole->name,true,array('disabled'))}}
```

Comment: On disabling the check box  value not storing in db

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `readonly` in options:

```
{{Form::checkbox('allRole[]', $allRole->name, true, ['readonly'=>true])}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write onlcick function for the checkbox to get checked first and then make it readonly. You can use onclick as,

```
{{ Form::checkbox('name', 'value', true, ['onClick' => 'alert(123)']) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by Mr. Zoltan Toth:

```
<input type='checkbox' />

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();

return false;

alert('Break');
)};
```

[preventing checkbox from changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610249/prevent-checkbox-from-ticking-checking-completely)