# How do I prevent checkbox value changes until later?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Scenario: I have a use case where I have a checkbox, that when clicked will show a modal window with a Save option. What I am focusing on is the checkbox. I need to prevent the checkbox from changing its value or being unchecked until after I take action on the modal popup. Whatever the case, I simply need to know how to prevent the checkbox from not being checked or value changed until a later time.

How can this be accomplished in JavaScript? Again, no uncheck of the checkbox and no value change until a later time - i.e promise resolves. Just need to know about handling the checkbox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent checkbox from ticking/checking COMPLETELY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610249/prevent-checkbox-from-ticking-checking-completely)

Comment: @TodorSimeonov No because that was not a good thread towards what I was given here for the answer. That is why I tagged it angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a checkbox and use `ng-change` event to handle the unchecking of checkbox,

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model = "checkboxValue" ng-change="handleChange()" />
```

And add this logic in your controller,

```
app.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.checkboxValue = true;

  let canUncheck = false;

  $scope.handleChange = function(){
    if(!canUncheck && !$scope.checkboxValue){
      $scope.checkboxValue = true;
    }
  }


  //later when checkbox can be unchecked
  canUncheck = true;$scope.checkboxValue = false;
})
```

See this [pen](https://codepen.io/anuragasaurus/pen/VbVjEB).

Comment: this works awesome except one issue. Once I resolve and later changes the values, the checkbox is now false. But when I then go to the checkbox to check it true, I don't want the modal to popup. Is this understandable or do I need to add a pen?