# Angular : uncheck indeterminate checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox

I have very simple requirement. Lets say checkbox has three states, indeterminate, checked & unchecked.
What I want :

- When click on indeterminate checkbox it should uncheck
- When click on checked checkbox it should uncheck
- When click on unchecked checkbox it should checked

But in angular2 I am not able to get solve first requirement. Whatever I do, when click on indeterminate checkbox it get checked (Not expected).

Please check [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-states?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  milestone = { status: "crossed" };
  checkMilestone(milestone) {
    switch (milestone.status) {
      case "crossed": {
        milestone.status = "unchecked";
        break;
      }
      case "unchecked": {
        milestone.status = "checked";
        break;
      }
      case "checked": {
        milestone.status = "unchecked";
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" [indeterminate]="milestone?.status === 'crossed'" [checked]="milestone?.status === 'checked'" (change)="checkMilestone(milestone)"> Status: {{ milestone?.status }}
```

I want to implement parent child checkbox and select all functionality similar to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dipaktelangre/2ajwLqkd/) but in angular.

Comment: I can recall about an angular reminder about checkboxes and model binding against checked property: as long as I can remember, the checked property doesn't work (or better, is ignored) when the model change, but I might be wrong. Did you try binding a model instead? you could just use one condition, which is setting indeterminate if the model is either null or undefined.

Comment: I mean something like that: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-states-hgy56j?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @briosheje Thank you so much! Its working as you suggested !!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve that, just update the code to the following:

HTML:

```
<input #input type="checkbox" [indeterminate]="milestone?.status === 'crossed'" 
(click)="checkMilestone($event)"
> Status: {{ milestone?.status }}
```

TypeScript:

```
  checkMilestone(e) {
    
    switch (this.milestone.status) {
      case "crossed": {
        e.target.checked = false;
        this.milestone.status = "unchecked";
        break;
      }
      case "unchecked": {
        this.milestone.status = "checked";
        break;
      }
      case "checked": {
        this.milestone.status = "unchecked";
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

something for reference:
[Prevent checkbox from ticking/checking COMPLETELY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610249/prevent-checkbox-from-ticking-checking-completely)