# how to set input type checkbox border and background?

Tags: html, css

I need to set an input type checkbox right side padding to `10px` and `border-right:1px solid #000`. I am trying this but the checkbox not taking the values. Does anybody know why it isn't working?

I am using the following code:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  border-right:1px solid #fff;
  margin-right:10px;
}
```

The border doesn't take.

Comment: I tried something at http://fiddle.jshell.net/edn8E/ and http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/xP2Ns/ have a look

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986608/css-styling-checkboxes

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those elements what browsers tend not to let you style that much, and mostly people replace it with javascript.

Why dont you give pretty checkbox a try? :) 
http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettycheckboxes/

**Edit:**

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/v4Dde/2/ this is how i made it once with out javascript, hope it helps you (sorry about the color just made them this way so you can see :) )

Answer (score 1):

Have you try using outline instead of border ?

For example :

```
outline : 2px solid #000000;
```