# HTML/CSS Custom checkbox Button Image Issue

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have been trying to get Custom checkboxes to work with my site. However, I've run into a puzzling issue with a specific part of my HTML.

Here is my current code:
HTML

```
<div class="quicklinks_login">
    <label for="cookieuser" style="padding-left: 7px;"><input type='checkbox' name='cookieuser' value='1' tabindex='10' id='cb_cookieuser_navbar' accesskey='c' />&nbsp;Remember Me</label>
</div>
```

CSS

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label,
label > input[type="checkbox"] {
    background: url("../images/override/state_off.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Now, as you can see from my CSS, I have two patterns that I want to be styled. The label > input[type="checkbox"] 'pattern'  *should* be applied to my HTML (which it is, according to FireBug). However, the custom image does not display with the checkbox.

To sum it up, my question is simple: Why is the 'pattern' `label > input[type="checkbox"]` not working for my HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize checkboxes and radio buttons with just CSS if you prefer. https://www.google.com/search?q=css%20only%20custom%20checkbox . The basic idea is to style the label and hide the actual checkbox. Clicking on the label sets/unsets the checkbox, so all the form functionality is retained. The only downside is that old versions of IE require a graceful fallback, which most of the solutions provide.

Answer (score 1):

> This is one of those elements what browsers tend not to let you style
>   that much, and mostly people replace it with javascript.

answere on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412511/how-to-set-input-type-checkbox-border-and-background) by @levente-nagy