# set background to dynamically created check box and text in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to apply background to each check box and separated by some space. Is it possible to apply background to dynamically created check box in **div**

I have to set background to this line.

`'<input type="checkbox" value="'+ ar2[i] + "   " + "   " + ar1[i] + '"/>'
            + ar1[i] + "   " + "   " + ar2[i] + '</br>' + '</br>' + '</br>'`

```
    for ( var i = 0; i < ar2.length; i++) {
        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="checkbox" value="'+ ar2[i] + "   " + "   " + ar1[i] + '"/>' + ar1[i] + "   " + "   " + ar2[i] + '</br>' + '</br>' + '</br>' );
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    }
```

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986608/css-styling-checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
classx="classname";
for ( var i = 0; i < ar2.length; i++) {
        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input class="'+classx+'" type="checkbox" value="'+ ar2[i] + "   " + "   " + ar1[i] + '"/>' + ar1[i] + "   " + "   " + ar2[i] + '</br>' + '</br>' + '</br>' );
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    }
```

You may create custom classes in css and assign one class name to `classx` and it will apply the class to the dynamically created checkbox. The checkbox will get styled accordingly.