# is there anyway to change background color of check box?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, jquery-plugins

i want to change inner background color of Checkbox  **i mean the white square**
i searched too much but the most of the article simply said create the div and change the background color of div but this method doesn't change the white square.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style checkbox using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: Check out a similar question for a possible solution. Hope this helps!
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986608/css-styling-checkboxes

Answer (score 2):

Checkboxes (also radio and select) are not like other HTML elements. They're tied closely to the standard controls that are part of the operating system. You don't have much control over how they are rendered.

There are [JavaScript-based alternative](http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/)s (and even some [clever CSS hacks](http://andymcfee.com/2012/05/01/css3-toggle-switch-a-ui-alternative-to-checkboxes/) that use overlays) but the controls themselves cannot be styled the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers use the native checkbox style of the underlying operating system. I would use HTML/CSS/JS to create a custom checkbox, that you can style however you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common question because checkboxes aren't typical HTML elements. Here's a pretty good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css). Know your issue isn't without solution, its just not as easy as it might be with "standard" CSS3. Here's a nice [tool](http://csscheckbox.com/) to generate checboxes without javascript.