# Change check box color when its enabled

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I've the following check-box and I need that when the checkBox is 
**checked** that the color of the **V** will be in green ,how should I do that?

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"  />
```

This is  not working

```
<style type="text/css">
    input[type=checkbox], input[type=file] {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label::after {
        border: 3px solid #228B22;
        border-top: none;
        border-right: none;
    }


    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 1.2ex;
        height: 0.4ex;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        top: 0.9ex;
        left: 0.4ex;
        border: 3px solid #1062a4;
        border-top: none;
        border-right: none;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: See this answer for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/1986931/961695 but for more control and styles search for a jQuery plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE *****

I edit the FIDDLE and this is what you need (enable = green and disable for the heck of it):

```
input[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label::after {
    border: 3px solid #228B22;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
}


input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   width: 1.2ex;
   height: 0.4ex;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   top: 0.9ex;
   left: 0.4ex;
   border: 3px solid #1062a4;
   border-top: none;
   border-right: none;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cwM87/69/)

Comment: do you understand the OP's question? Here it is (very clearly) ***I need that when the checkBox is checked that the color of the V will be in green***

Comment: Thanks but this is not working ,the V mark is not changing his color...any other idea?

Comment: HI Riskbreaker i've add it to my css file in the edit operation file like the follow post and its not working despite I saw that it is in the fiddle,any idea what could be the problem ,or how to debug it?

Comment: Please see my updated post,thanks!btw voted up for the support

Comment: Can you add yours to fiddle? Are you also adding the position elements?

Comment: I use the code as is ,do I need to omit the position?