# How to remove circle on background of checkbox?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to show a check-box in a popup screen. Actually my checkbox is rounded. I need no rounded background and tick should be green as show in image. I need checkbox will be placed on right side and having no background but have green color.

Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cBR2AcneBvbUCvHqwHIh?p=preview
please click on the button to check checkbox .

```
  <ion-popover-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">My Popover Title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
<ion-content><ul class="list" ng-repeat="item in a">
<li class="item item-checkbox"><label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" ></label>{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
</ion-content>
  </ion-popover-view>
```

I need it like this:

Comment: What does your first image show? It is the same as the last image to me.

Comment: I am not able to upload ..both image are same

Comment: so the first image can be delete from the question? If it has no point remove it.

Comment: please check image I want to make checkbok like that

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Styling Checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986608/css-styling-checkboxes)

Comment: hmm but it different from this Qyuestion

Comment: You can use the same technique as given in the accepted answer from Jeff B in your case. Can't you?

Comment: I am trying could you post your answer with plunker

Comment: The answer there has a jsfiddle showing how you can do it: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/xP2Ns/ You just need to provide your own image with the green check icon. Otherwise you can do the same thing.

Comment: but how it is become right.how checkbox on right and text on left

Comment: you can put any image instead of green ,But it should be on right and text on left

Comment: thanks but not good anser..@@

Comment: Btw. Have you tried changing `<input type="checkbox test" >` to `<input type="checkbox" >`? Then you have an image. I guess you just would need to change the image in the ionic style you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try like this, i think the same you expected
plnkr.co/edit/fHdnWwIRgi5jFLQlCWKs?p=preview